# How to solve low memory available in Arduino

Tags: arduino, arduino-ide, arduino-c++

I'm using this code:

```cpp
#include <HCSR04.h>
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
#include <ArduinoJson.h>
#include <Wire.h>
#include "RTClib.h"

#define buzzer 2

//initialisation class HCSR04 (trig pin , echo pin)
HCSR04 hcAir(13, 12);
HCSR04 hcPakan(11, 10);

SoftwareSerial s(5, 6);
RTC_DS3231 rtc;
char daysOfTheWeek[7][12] = {"Minggu", "Senin", "Selasa", "Rabu", "Kamis", "Jum'at", "Sabtu"};

StaticJsonBuffer<1000> jsonBuffer;
JsonObject& root = jsonBuffer.createObject();

void setup() {
  s.begin(115200);
  pinMode(buzzer, OUTPUT);
  rtc.begin();
}

void air() {
  int air = hcAir.dist();
  int rumus = ((100 / 50) * air);
  int isiAir = 100 - rumus;

  if (isiAir <= 0) {
    root["air"] = 0;
    digitalWrite(buzzer, HIGH);
  } else if (isiAir >= 100) {
    root["air"] = 100;
    digitalWrite(buzzer, LOW);
  } else {
    root["air"] = isiAir;
    digitalWrite(buzzer, LOW);
  }
}

void pakan() {
  int pakan = hcPakan.dist();
  int rumus2 = ((100 / 50) * pakan);
  int isiPakan = 100 - rumus2;

  if (isiPakan <= 0) {
    root["pakan"] = 0;
    digitalWrite(buzzer, HIGH);
  } else if (isiPakan >= 100) {
    root["pakan"] = 100;
    digitalWrite(buzzer, LOW);
  } else {
    root["pakan"] = isiPakan;
    digitalWrite(buzzer, LOW);
  }
}

void waktu() {
  DateTime now = rtc.now();
  int jam = now.hour();
  int menit = now.minute();
  String hari = daysOfTheWeek[now.dayOfTheWeek()];

  root["jam"] = jam;
  root["menit"] = menit;
  root["hari"] = hari;
}

void loop() {
  air();
  pakan();
  waktu();

  if (s.available() > 0) {
    root.printTo(s);
  }
}
```

This message appears which causes the code to not run:

```
Sketch uses 10468 bytes (32%) of program storage space. Maximum is 32256 bytes.
Global variables use 1608 bytes (78%) of dynamic memory, leaving 440 bytes for local variables. Maximum is 2048 bytes.
    Low memory available, stability problems may occur.
```

Comment: Personally for writing Json I'd format it myself on a small microcontroller instead of using a library, but isn't your buffer size of 1000 a lot larger than you'd need? It looks to me as though something more like 200 would be enough.

Comment: It's not the message that causes the code not to run. However, you're lucky to get such a warning. (Seem to point you into the right direction)

Answer (score 0):

Try to see what the absolute maximum size of your Json can be, and reduce the buffer size (`StaticJsonBuffer<1000>`) to that hopefully lower number.

Also, for simple Json you can do things "by hand" and not use the library. You could also simply send name/value pairs and don't use Json at all.